# Copying multiple files from one subdirectory to another with wildcards

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh

I'm having issues with wildcard copying on a folder set that I'm working with, and was wondering what the best way to copy these files would be. For instance, my folder structure looks like this:

```
000
    001
        001
            medium
                image1.jpg

            original
                image1.jpg

            thumb
                image1.jpg
        002
            medium
                anotherimage2.jpg

            original
                anotherimage2.jpg

            thumb
                anotherimage2.jpg
        003
            medium
                someimage3.jpg

            original
                someimage3.jpg

            thumb
                someimage3.jpg
    002
        001
            medium
                whome_anotherimage_00002.jpg

            original
                whome_anotherimage_00002.jpg

            thumb
                whome_anotherimage_00002.jpg
        002
            medium
                crapnotthisagain_067.jpg

            original
                crapnotthisagain_067.jpg

            thumb
                crapnotthisagain_067.jpg
```

What I need to do is have a bash/zsh script, or some command that will recursively move the image from the original folder in each directory to the thumb directory, overwriting the thumb image.

So far, using `find` or `cp` is throwing me mixed results. I got closer with

```
find 000/*/*/original/ -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec cp '{}' 000/*/*/thumb/ ';'
```

but that only copies the files to the last `thumb` directory that it finds. Is there a better way to script this?

Update:

Running the following:

```
find 000000/*/*/original/ -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec cp -t 000000/*/*/thumb/ '{}' +
```

throws me this on a mac

```
cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

and on ubuntu: (and doesn't copy anything)

```
cp: omitting directory ‘000000/001/998/thumb/’
cp: omitting directory ‘000000/001/999/thumb/’
```

Comment: Try specifying the destination first, and placing `{} ';'` at the end: `-exec cp -t 000/*/*/thumb '{}'  ';'`

Comment: Find doesn't like the `-t` option for me: `find 000/*/*/original/ -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec cp -t 000/*/*/thumb '{}' ';'` `cp: illegal option -- t`

Comment: What error do you get from `-t` option? The `-t` option is for `cp`. I just tried the following command and it copied the files as expected: `find source/dir -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec cp -t dest/dir '{}' ';'`

Comment: Also you can use `{}  +` instead of `{} ';'` to make the copying more efficient.

Comment: it throws the `cp: illegal option -- t` when using that option on cp

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I just learned that [bsd `cp`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?cp) do not support `-t option`

Comment: Yeah, I just put the output in my question above for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looping over the results from find, then use substring replacement to change "original" to "thumb" in the variable:

```
for i in $(find 000/*/*/original -type f -name '*.jpg'); do cp ${i} ${i/original/thumb}; done
```

Comment: Yeah! This worked perfectly. That's exactly what I needed.